# Custom Cell with protocol to check changes in UISwitch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I created a `custom cell` and a `protocol` to be aware of the changes on the `UISwitch`. I think i have everything i need but i can't get the func `didChangeSwitchState` to be triggered.

VouchersViewController.swift

```
// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:VouchersFilterCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! VouchersFilterCell
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.vouchersFilters[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

// MARK: - VouchersFilterCellDelegate

func didChangeSwitchState(sender: VouchersFilterCell, isOn: Bool) {
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: sender)
    debugPrint(indexPath?.row)
}
```

BaseCell.swift

```
class BaseCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        // code common to all your cells goes here
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

    func setupViews(){
    }
}
```

VouchersFilterCell.swift

```
protocol VouchersFilterCellDelegate: class {
    func didChangeSwitchState(sender: VouchersFilterCell, isOn: Bool)
}

class VouchersFilterCell: BaseCell {

    // MARK: - UIComponent

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let filterSwitch: UISwitch = {
        let fSwitch = UISwitch()
        fSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handledSwitchChange(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return fSwitch
    }()

    weak var delegate: VouchersFilterCellDelegate?

    // MARK: - Life Cycle    

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    // MARK: - Setup

    override func setupViews() {
        addSubview(titleLabel)
        addSubview(filterSwitch)

        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-13-[v0]-13-|", views: titleLabel)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-16-[v0]-16-[v1]-16-|", views: titleLabel, filterSwitch)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-7-[v0]", views: filterSwitch)
    }

    // MARK: - IBAction 

    @IBAction func handledSwitchChange(sender: UISwitch) {
        self.delegate?.didChangeSwitchState(sender: self, isOn:filterSwitch.isOn)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `handledSwitchChange` being called?

Comment: @RyanPoolos No, nothing

Comment: Ok so then your delegate might be fine. It looks like its how you setup your Switch. I notice the method is marked IBAction? but you're creating your own filterSwitch in code. Are you using Interface Builder for this? Where is setupViews being called?

Comment: setupViews its called on init and i'm creating the view in code. Removed the IBAction but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you include your init method and any other code for your cell please. That may be part of the problem.

Comment: I also notice in your `handledSwitchChange` you're using `filterSwitch.isOn` but should be using `sender.isOn` likely not he bug but something worth changing.

Comment: You also need to turn on autolayout for your `fSwitch` with `fSwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: Are you using the proper init? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell#discussion

Comment: @RyanPoolos still no luck, think i'm just gonna do it in some other way

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ i would say yes, no problem att building the view. Only at using the switch

Comment: @bruno could you  try with my answer

Comment: Do you know for sure *your* init is being called? The basic init() may not be called when dequeued.

Comment: Try changing `let filterSwitch: UISwitch = {` to `lazy var filterSwitch: UISwitch = {` you're setting self to as the target but I'm not sure self is setup for a constant.

Comment: @RyanPoolos lazy... did the trick ;) post the answer

Comment: ah tricky one. I wonder if that's a bug or should be a compiler warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we figured out together in the comments it seems like a let property is created before self is ready so the Switch target is nil. Changing to a lazy var ensures self is created first.

```
lazy var filterSwitch: UISwitch = {
    let fSwitch = UISwitch()
    fSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handledSwitchChange(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    return fSwitch
}()
```

Comment: I always have done my views as `lazy var` because I don't believe Swift 1.0 allowed lets to be setup this way. So this never happened to me before. But its definitely very good to know!